# Получение ширины консоли

Tags: javascript, node.js, консоль

При запуске скрипта напрямую через `node run.js` **process.stdout.columns** отрабатывает нормально и возвращает количество допустимых символов. При запуске скрипта через команду, созданную в package.json, `npm run build`, которая запускает по сути ту же команду `node run.js`, **process.stdout.columns** возвращает **undefined**.

Как это пофиксить и, главное, хочется знать, почему так происходит?

Comment: только что проверил ошибку которую вы описали, у меня все работает, как бы я не запускал, и `npm` или напрямую из `node index.js` и если npm запускает npm команду `node -v v6.3.1`

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев очень странно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем одно и тоже. Запуская через package.json фактически выполняется команда через exec.
 Судя по всему вызывается как дочерний процесс и он не будет иметь прямой связи с TTY таким образом у stdio не будет TTY потоков.
Тут было обсуждение на эту тему https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/2333